# Codeigniter inserting value into array

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I asked a question on SO a few hours back.

How to insert an Array of field names from a form into SQL database in Codeigniter.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][name]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][address]" value=""><br></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][age]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][email]" value=""></td>
```

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][name]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][address]" value=""><br></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][age]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][email]" value=""></td>
</tr>
..........//so on
```

This is the best answer I got

```
foreach($_POST['user'] as $user)
 {
    $this->db->insert('mytable', $user);
 }
```

Now I want to pass a id generated from user session data into this array + a few other values like current time

Is it possible to tweak the above solution?

[The Previous Discussion Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849414/codeigniter-insert-multiple-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['user'] as &$user)
 {
    $user['additional_data'] = $_SESSION['additional_data'];
    $user['current_time'] = time();
    $this->db->insert('mytable', $user);
 }
```

Note the & in &$user which is a pass by reference  which allows manipulation of an array within a foreach loop.  If you reference user later remember to unset($user) to remove the reference to the last element of the $_POST['user'] array.

Comment: Spot on! It seems to be a conspiracy against me. I try all variations which throw all kinds of errors at me, then someone @ SO works it out in a millisecond. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Actually, looking at it, you can ignore the pass by reference (& before &$user) and it should still work.  Passing by reference is only useful if you use the $_POST['user'] array anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes, I didnt have to use the '&'.

Comment: It works but I dont understand it. In what sequence is the array deconstructed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm missing something here, but can't you just remove the `foreach` and build your code like this:

```
$var1 = $_POST['user_var1'] * 3 + 1 / 5;
$this->db->insert('mytable', $var1);
$var2 = gettime();
$this->db->insert('mytable', $var2);
....
```

(where gettime() should be replace with whatever the PHP command for getting time is, plus maybe a formatting function)

Comment: the form fields are generated dynamically. Thats why I need a loop.