# Codeigniter Inserting Multidimensional Array as rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please Refer to this question I asked
[Codeigniter Insert Multiple Rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849414/codeigniter-insert-multiple-rows-in-sql/3850285#3850285)

To restate

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][name]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][address]" value=""><br></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][age]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[0][email]" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][name]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][address]" value=""><br></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][age]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user[1][email]" value=""></td>
</tr>
..........
```

Can Be Inserted into MySQL as this

```
 foreach($_POST['user'] as $user)
{
    $this->db->insert('mytable', $user);
}
```

This results in multiple MySQL queries. Is it possible to optimise it further, so that the insert occurs in one query

Something like this

[insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql/780046#780046)

but taking advantage of codeigniters simpler syntax. Thanks

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of thousands of records to INSERT, you won't gain anything and the real bottleneck are the table indexes, and not the round-trip cost of running the query multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data);
```

Check the [code igniter user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter does not seem to have a mutli-insert method. Moreover, even if it had, you may run into issues like:

- Hitting the maximum query length cap
- Having to lock the table until inserts are done
- Dealing with errors can be a bit harder
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 2 (upcoming release) will have a batch insert method.

Comment: thanks, i am already using ci 2, will look up the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In CI 2, there is a `set_insert_batch()` Active Record function.

Comment: No documentation though, and an array I assembled doesn't get inserted