# Multiple insert queries based on select?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

That's my queries below:

```
$result4 = $this->db->query('SELECT team_leader_id FROM teams WHERE team_money < 0')->result_array();
$this->db->insert( 'd_teams', array( 'leader_id' => $result4[0]['team_leader_id'] ) );
```

Yes, it works but it works for only 1 row and there can be multiple or even 50 for example. How I can edit that so it will support all available rows that the select query return? So, it will insert them all in separate rows in the d_teams table.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, basically, you are trying to turn all `team_leader_id` listings from the `teams` table into new `leader_id` listings in the `d_teams` table (where `team_money` is negative)?

Comment: you could use `insert_batch` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849414/codeigniter-insert-multiple-rows-in-sql#answer-14332078

Comment: Exactly, on the condition from `teams` table `WHERE team_money <0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is possible with a subquery:

```sql
INSERT INTO d_teams (leader_id) (SELECT team_leader_id FROM teams WHERE team_money < 0);
```

So, in your code:

```php
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO d_teams (leader_id) (SELECT team_leader_id FROM teams WHERE team_money < 0)');
```

Comment: I believe it will work yeah .. but isn't it better to use foreach as this dude suggested below?

Comment: I mean in terms of server load, which one is better mostly ?

Comment: This one is the best in terms of server load as it generates the least amount of communication between your web service and your database instance. The foreach-method generates most traffic of all suggestions.

Every time you use any command related to MySQL, messages are sent back an forth between the web service and database. The more data you can send in each message, the less of an overhead is the message passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `insert` function inside a loop that runs through the `$result4`:

```
$result4 = $this->db->query('SELECT team_leader_id FROM teams WHERE team_money < 0')->result_array();

foreach($result4 as $result) {
    $this->db->insert( 'd_teams', array( 'leader_id' => $result['team_leader_id'] ) );
}
```

Perhaps there is another way to insert multiple lines. But this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer explains how to perform bulk inserts using CodeIgniter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17875754/365296

In your case, I guess applying that would look something like this:

```
$result4 = $this->db->query('SELECT ... ')->result_array();
$teams = array_map(function ($dbRow) {
    return array('leader_id' => $dbRow['team_leader_id']);
}, $result4);
$this->db->insert_batch('d_teams', $teams);
```

Comment: isn't foreach a better method than that actually or even directly subquery?

Comment: In PHP everying is slow, so if performance is an issue, don't use it. ;) But if you have to, the faster approach would be to have your MySQL server do as much work as possible, which in this case would be to use a subquery.

Comment: so the subquery as someone suggested will be better approach in terms of server load and etc right otherwise it doesn't matter mostly, right?

Comment: It could matter if the web service and the database instance are far away from each other physically, or there is some other performance issue present in their communication, as each query generates a communication dealt with serially. If the message passing overhead is about 10 ms, and you use the foreach-method with 4000 teams, just passing messages would take 10 ms * 4000 = 40 seconds. That's a long time to wait for a web page to load.